# How long should I wait before watering my Cat's Claw vines in high heat?

Tags: watering, vines

I was told to water everyday in summer time. I live in Las Vegas and we have had a heat wave for a week with temps over 110 °F. I watered each day and the 6 vines all are losing their leaves and seem to be dying. I think I may have watered too much.

How long should I wait to water again?

Comment: A photograph would be very helpful ...

Comment: There are several plants called [Cat's Claw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_claw). Can your confirm that you're referring to [_Dolichandra unguis-cati_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolichandra_unguis-cati)?

Comment: Even though the heat is crazy high, make sure that your plants actually need the water, that the soil is dryish before watering again.  Over 90 degrees F plants tend to stop producing their food and soon go into a stress mode.  Stress mode is first defined by loss of leaves.  The plant is just not able to produce food for itself.  Even if there is plenty of water, the temperatures are inhibiting food production, water delivery.  The plant is trying to reduce the need to make food and have less plant material to care for...most plants will react like this to severe heat to survive.